# autocomplete in SQL server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In other IDEs, there are ways (e.g. control + space in netbeans on mac) to ask for suggestions on autocompletion. I was just wondering if there is similar function in SQL server management studio? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: `Intellisense` is totally **shit** in SSMS. Install a third party software.

Comment: You don't have to press anything it will automatically show the suggestions . Make sure it enabled to show suggestions once in a blue moon

Comment: When Intellisense is running properly, you don't need to ask. When it's not, you can ask all you want, but get nothing. @Prdp - can you recommend something for that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e8064cb-58d8-4eb3-a88c-d8f9a167ccca

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: I sometimes find SSMS hard to use as well. Do you have a recommendation on an alternative IDE that you think is best suited for SQL?

Comment: @dzjustinli2 - I guess to work in **T-SQL** `SSMS` is the best tool in my opinion. Except `Intellisense` it is good to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use few of ApexSQL's Free tools. Though there are little burden on IDE, it servers the purpose.

URL: https://www.apexsql.com/free/

Feel free to drop a message for further queries.

Comment: Every time I used on a script that has temporary tables, it crashes my sql studio instance, and lose what I worked.. NOT OK!!

Comment: Apexsql is no longer free. Thought I'd mention it just in case someone comes across this question like I have

Comment: @lzzy, thanks for adding the note. Yes, it is no longer a free product!!

Answer (score 5):

The IntelliSense will need to be refreshed when you add new objects.

Press

```
CTRL+SHIFT+R
```

to do this.

(for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 5):

Simply press ALT + Right Arrow to show the suggestions.